# MySQL Query returns duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am very new to SQL

when I execute the below query it returns the following results:

```
SELECT table1.image_name, table1.item_id
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table2.catagory="item"
AND table3.account_id=59

image_name    image_id
-------------------------
d9.jpg      89
d9.jpg      89
d9.jpg      89
d9.jpg      89
d10.jpg      90
d10.jpg      90
d10.jpg      90
d10.jpg      90
etc.....
```

The results repeat the same attribute four times! I don't understand why this is and I cannot find a reason for this anywhere!

I have 3 tables, table1 PK(image_id) is referenced as the FK in Item. Item PK(Item_id) is referenced with FK in table3. table3 has a compound key from table 4(account_id) and table2(item_id).

My query is clearly wrong, but I don't understand why? I hope someone could provide an explanation to the result!, or help point me in the right direction!

Thanks

Comment: Is the query run in PHP? If so please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get multiple results because you do not specify join conditions. Foreign key relations are good, but you need to specify that they apply in your query:

```
SELECT table1.image_name, table1.item_id
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table2.catagory="item"
AND table3.account_id=59
AND table1.id = table2.item_id
AND table2.item_id = table3.id
```

Note the last two conditions. You need to change them to match your needs.

Comment: Thank you Arjan for the advice!

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

you are listing 3 tables, and only joining on two of them.
that means you will get a row back from the join, and it will repeat once for every row in the third table (table1 in your case)

Comment: i see by reading more carefully that you actually are not even joining anything...  you should have part of your WHERE clause that links the tables like AND table1.id = table2.id etc.

Answer (score 3):

you have to state the join conditions explicitly - otherwise you get cartesian product of all 3 tables for all items 59

```
where table1.image_id = table2.item_id
and table2.item_id = table3.item_id
and ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DISTINCT` in this case because you have mulitple rows matching the same information:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.image_name, table1.item_id 
FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE table2.catagory="item" 
AND table3.account_id=59
```

However, as the others mention, you need to specify the conditions for joining the tables you're using, something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.image_name, table1.item_id 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 on table2.item_id = table1.item_id
JOIN table3 on table3.item_id = table1.item_id
WHERE table2.catagory="item" 
AND table3.account_id=59
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.image_name, table1.item_id 
FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.item_id = table2.item_id 
AND table1.item_id = table2.item_id
AND table2.catagory="item" 
AND table3.account_id=59
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but in addition to adding 'Distinct' as the above poster suggested, I think you also need to put the relationship between table 3 and table 2 in your Where clause.  From what you described I think something like the below would work.  May need some additional conditions depending on the actual structure of the tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.image_name, table1.item_id 
FROM table1, table2, table3 
WHERE    table2.catagory="item"
 AND table3.account_id=59 
 AND table3.item_id = table2.item_id
```

Comment: @achusonline, Randy, darkajax and juergen,aelfric Thanks everyone for the explination, how can I vote for everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT table1.image_name, table1.item_id FROM table1, table2, table3 WHERE    table2.catagory="item" AND table3.account_id=59`

though that is more like a workaround..

If you may specify the tables' structure more clearly, it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

There might be some columns you are not selecting which will make the row look unique. So, may be your query is working fine, however, since you are not selecting all the columns, they appear as duplicate rows.